# How can I have reference for drawableTop of a Button?

Tags: android, kotlin

I declared a drawable inside my Button and I want to get a reference for that because I created a method where I display a Dialog, extract the text and drawable of that button and use it to change the text and icon of a dialog dynamically.

Please do check this snippet:

```
private fun showProductDialog(button : Button){
        //extract product info selected from button

        //show dialog
        val dialog = Dialog(this)
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_product)
        //set text and icon
        val titleLayout = dialog.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.ll_product_label)
        val titleText = titleLayout.findViewById<HelveticaBoldTextView>(R.id.tv_category_click)
        val titleIcon = titleLayout.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iv_product_icon)

        //get text of button, set to titleText
        titleText.text = button.text.toString().uppercase()

        //extract drawableTop of Button then
        //set image for titleIcon = drawable in Button
        
        dialog.show()
    }
```

Edited, I added this line inside my showProductDialog() but the issue is it rescaled my button's image too when clicked. No errors but my guess is that the button.compoundDrawables not only get all the drawables, but also set the image on my button. Since my image in dialog is set to 24x24 dp, my button clicked also set to 24x24.

```
//extract drawableTop of Button then
        //set image for titleIcon = drawable in Button
        val drawables = button.compoundDrawables
        titleIcon.setImageDrawable(drawables[1])
```

Comment: Why do you need a reference . You already know which drawable you set just save it in a variable and pass the same to `Dialog` .

Comment: Just for some clarifications, I have multiple button for each product category and I don't want to declare each one of them in a variable. I want to dynamically create a dialog based on the buttons text and image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get DrawableTop you can use this

```
val compoundDrawables = button?.compoundDrawables
val drawable = compoundDrawables?.get(1)
```

To set DrawableTop you can use this

```
 button?.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.icon, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I did use that button.compoundDrawables to get all the drawables in my button. The problem is that it also sets the button's drawable.
By the way, Im using kotlin and it does not have getCompoundDrawables but instead it has compoundDrawables(get/set) functionality. Issue is that it does NOT only get the drawable, but it also resets the buttons's drawable.

Comment: updated code to kotlin. Please try this, 
It will only get drawable. 
You can use set DrawableTop code to set it back